# Dovecot bounces messages because of over quota ignoring quota_rule2

Tags: email-server, dovecot, quota

I'm trying to configure quotas. I want to set a default quota (say 10GB) and allow +100MB for the trash. I also need to be able to set a custom quota for an user. My users come from LDAP/AD.

I'm able to set the default quota and defining a custom one for an user. This work great.

Now, I'm trying to allow 100MB more for the trash.

To test that, I sent a couples emails to my test account and defined a low quota (10MB) for this account. I made my quota over 140%. I then moved all my mails to the trash folder.

I'm still over quota because I didn't emptied the trash, but because I have a quota_rule2 that say allow 100MB more for the trash, I expect to be able to still receive mail for this account.

When the account receive a new mail, it bounces because the account is over quota, but it shouldn't because all mails are in the trash and all the others folders are empty.

```
# doveconf -n
# 2.2.33.2 (d6601f4ec): /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# Pigeonhole version 0.4.21 (92477967)
# OS: Linux 4.15.0-43-generic x86_64 Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS 
auth_default_realm = example.com
doveadm_password =  # hidden, use -P to show it
doveadm_port = 53683
first_valid_uid = 200
last_valid_uid = 200
mail_attachment_dir = /var/vmail/attachments
mail_attachment_hash = %{sha1}.%{size}
mail_location = mbox:~/mail:INBOX=/var/mail/%u
mail_plugins = " notify replication zlib quota"
mail_privileged_group = mail
managesieve_notify_capability = mailto
managesieve_sieve_capability = fileinto reject envelope encoded-character vacation subaddress comparator-i;ascii-numeric relational regex imap4flags copy include variables body enotify environment mailbox date index ihave duplicate mime foreverypart extracttext
mdbox_rotate_interval = 1 days
namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes
  location = 
  mailbox Drafts {
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox Junk {
    special_use = \Junk
  }
  mailbox Sent {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox "Sent Messages" {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox Trash {
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  prefix = 
}
passdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-ldap.conf.ext
  driver = ldap
}
plugin {
  mail_replica = tcp:mail2.example.com:53683
  quota = count:User quota
  quota_grace = 10%%
  quota_rule = *:storage=10G
  quota_rule2 = Trash:storage=+100M
  quota_vsizes = yes
  quota_warning = storage=95%% quota-warning 95 %u
  quota_warning2 = storage=80%% quota-warning 80 %u
  sieve = /var/vmail/%d/%n/.dovecot.sieve
  sieve_before = /var/vmail/sieve/before.sieve
  sieve_default = /var/vmail/sieve/default.sieve
  sieve_global = /var/vmail/sieve/global
  zlib_save = lz4
}
protocols = " imap lmtp sieve"
service aggregator {
  fifo_listener replication-notify-fifo {
    user = vmail
  }
  unix_listener replication-notify {
    user = vmail
  }
}
service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    mode = 0666
  }
}
service doveadm {
  inet_listener {
    port = 53683
    ssl = no
  }
}
service imap-login {
  inet_listener imap {
    port = 0
  }
  process_min_avail = 10
}
service lmtp {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-lmtp {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0660
    user = postfix
  }
}
service quota-warning {
  executable = script /usr/local/bin/quota-warning.sh
  unix_listener quota-warning {
    user = vmail
  }
  user = dovecot
}
service replicator {
  process_min_avail = 1
}
ssl = required
ssl_cert = </etc/ssl/example.com.crtbundle
ssl_client_ca_dir = /etc/ssl/certs
ssl_key =  # hidden, use -P to show it
userdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-ldap.conf.ext
  driver = ldap
}
protocol lda {
  mail_plugins = " notify replication zlib quota sieve"
  postmaster_address = postmaster@example.com
}
protocol imap {
  mail_plugins = " notify replication zlib quota imap_quota"
}
protocol lmtp {
  mail_plugins = " notify replication zlib quota sieve"
  postmaster_address = postmaster@example.com

}

# cat dovecot-ldap.conf.ext
uris = (redacted)
dn = (redacted)
dnpass = (redacted)
auth_bind = yes
base = (redacted)
scope = subtree
deref = never
user_filter = (&(mail=%u)(&(|(objectclass=person))(!(UserAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))))
pass_filter = (&(mail=%u)(&(|(objectclass=person))(!(UserAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))))
iterate_attrs = mail=user # Used primarily by "doveadm" needed to users
iterate_filter = (objectclass=person)
user_attrs = \
  =quota_rule=*:storage=%{ldap:division:10G}, \
  =quota_rule2=Trash:storage=+100M, \
  =home=/var/vmail/%d/%{ldap:sAMAccountName}, \
  =mail=mdbox:/var/vmail/%d/%{ldap:sAMAccountName}/mdbox, \
  =uid=200, \
  =gid=200
```